# Replication vs Snapshot in HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera

We have two systems- One Offline system(Performance is not critical here), where the MapReduce jobs run on the HBase Cluster. The Other is the Online System(Performace is very critical here), where the API reads from the same HBase Cluster. But As the MapReduce jobs running on the same cluster, there are performance issues on the online system. So we are trying to set up separate HBase cluster for Offline system which is the replication of few family names from the Source cluster.
So on the source heavy MapReduce job runs. On the replicated cluster only online system runs giving the best performance.
My Question here is :: Cant we use Snap shot feature in HBase for doing the Same? I also wanted to know what is the difference between them?

Comment: This [article from Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/introduction-to-apache-hbase-snapshots/) goes thru snapshots in detail and also lists your particular scenario (last one on list of use cases).. hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use snapshot feature for mapreduce, it will also spend cpu, memory and disk io on live hbase cluster nodes too. So if disk io or cpu is the bottleneck for you, a seperate cluster for mapreduce jobs is better solution.

Comment: yes, disk io or cpu is the concern for me. we are opting for another cluster. Is it like, If we use Snapshot to load the data into the new cluster will also have performance issues on the source cluster?